# RestEasyReactive http response returns caught exception

Tags: java, http, quarkus, resteasy, reactive

I have a simple quarkus reactive resteasy server

```java
@Path("/")
@ApplicationScoped
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @RolesAllowed({"roleYouNeed"})
    public Uni<Response> hello(){
        return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.ok("hello").build());
    }
}
```

Following the documentation found here I create several exception mappers to return a response body which elaborates on the status code. This one for example works when you do not provide a JWT token to a request that needs it:

```java
@Provider//register as JAXRS provider
@Priority(1)//override the build-int mapper(which has 5001 prio)
@Slf4j
public class UnauthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnauthorizedException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(UnauthorizedException exception) {
        log.warn("There was an incoming request that did not have the correct Authorization");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity(new ErrorResponseObject().addErrorsItem(new ErrorResponseObjectErrorsInner()
                        .code(String.valueOf(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode()))
                        .detail("Unauthorized")))
                .build();
    }

}
```

This works as expected on my endpoint that uses quarkus-smallrye-jwt with the annotation `@RolesAllowed({"roleYouNeed"})`

When someone sends a token that is truly worthless however a JWTParse Exception occurs and a different exception is raised, the `AuthenticationFailedException`

To catch this one I created

```java
@Provider
@Priority(1)
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<AuthenticationFailedException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(AuthenticationFailedException exception) {
        log.warn("There was an incoming request that did not have the correct Authorization");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity(new ErrorResponseObject().addErrorsItem(new ErrorResponseObjectErrorsInner()
                        .code(String.valueOf(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode()))
                        .detail("Unauthorized")))
                .build();
    }
}
```

This does catch the exception and my warning is logged: `[com.ene.odp.exc.AuthenticationExceptionMapper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) There was an incoming request that did not have the correct Authorization` . The problem here is that a response has already been returned and I see the following error occurring:

```
2022-07-25 16:22:03,812 ERROR [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Request failed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to write
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.close(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:272)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.BasicServerJacksonMessageBodyWriter.writeResponse(BasicServerJacksonMessageBodyWriter.java:44)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:207)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.serialization.DynamicEntityWriter.write(DynamicEntityWriter.java:104)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResponseWriterHandler.handle(ResponseWriterHandler.java:31)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResponseWriterHandler.handle(ResponseWriterHandler.java:15)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext$1$1.handle(VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:73)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext$1$1.handle(VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:70)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:63)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.write(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:109)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.writeBlocking(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:224)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.close(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:270)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.checkValid(Http1xServerResponse.java:675)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.writeQueueFull(Http1xServerResponse.java:274)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.filters.AbstractResponseWrapper.writeQueueFull(AbstractResponseWrapper.java:486)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.awaitWriteable(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:116)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.write(ResteasyReactiveOutputStream.java:82)
```

Why is the response already being returned while I catch this exception? How can I make sure nothing is returned except what I return from the `AuthenticationExceptionMapper`?

Comment: Can you open a GitHub issue for this please?

Comment: Hi @geoand, I just opened [the issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26922)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem the right use case for `@Blocking`.
Did you try the following?

```
    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @RolesAllowed({"roleYouNeed"})
    public Response hello(){
        return Response.ok("hello").build();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Davide thanks for responding, the `@Blocking` was just a small leftover from the real implementation I'm trying to get to work. It does not alter the issue when the `@Blocking` is removed, and I would still like to be able to use it when it is in fact Blocking.

Comment: I don't expect it to alter the issue, I suspect is caused by something else. But you are showing in the question is non blocking, so that annotation shouldn't be necessary. And, if the code is blocking, do you need to return a Uni?

Comment: I removed it from the question to make it less confusing.